# Pandas - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function : `generateID` but I have a problem with this line :

`data_df['id_cont'] = data_df.apply(lambda row:row['product_name']+'-'+row['hour_shift'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),axis=1)`

Because of this data conversion problem I have this error :

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Here is my code :

```
 def generateID(self,outputMode,data_df):
    
    data_df = self._preGenerateID(outputMode,data_df)
    
    if outputMode.getModeCB() == CONST_MODE_CONT:
        data_df['id_cont'] = data_df.apply(lambda row:row['equipement']+'-'+row['product_name']+'-'+row['hour_shift'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),axis=1)
   
    else:
        data_df['first_date'] = data_df.groupby(['equipement'])['local_time'].transform('min')
        data_df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(data_df['first_date']).year
        data_df['year'] = data_df['year'].astype(str)

        data_df['id_batch'] = data_df.apply(lambda row:row['equipement']+'-'+row['product_name']+'-'+row['year'],axis=1)
 
    return data_df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your columns is a `float`, and I assume you want to concatenate them as `str` for `strftime`. You can try `f-strings`, or convert your column to `str` before concatenating.

`f-string` example:

```
data_df['id_cont'] = pd.to_datetime(df.apply(
          lambda row:f"{row['equipement']}-{row['product_name']}-{row['hour_shift']}",axis=1))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried your solution but I have this error : `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'`. I will convert my field `hour_shift` to `str`.

Comment: Oh wait you want to make a `datetime` object right? You need to use `strptime` instead. Or are you wanting to change the format of the `str`? Usually if you don't explicitly need the column in a different format, it is better to leave it as it is.

Comment: I want to make a datetime object, I will use `strptime`.

Comment: I have updated my answer to fit your solution

Comment: I'm responding a little late sorry, thank you very much for your help !